# Is it really that easy to move this network?

Tags: networking, datacenter

I am just wondering if maybe I am over simplifying things here.

I have a network housed in one data center in Seattle. We will be moving out of that data center this weekend. For the sake of keeping the network infrastructure as "clean" as possible I was just going to set it up in our new data center exactly as was in the old one.

My question is, instead of replicating everything and killing myself with stress over the week to complete this by Monday... Can I just lower the TTL times and then change the public IPs from that of the old DC to that of the new DC?

Will this keep everything going in theory?

Thanks,

Taylor

Comment: Considering we don't know what the "everything" that you're referring to is, there's no way to answer this. How about giving us some clues as to what "everything" is, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

First, we don't know what you're moving or what you mean by "clean".

But if this is a simple website or even dynamic sites (except data-driven applications since we need to consider your database), *you can simply point your DNS from the old IP to the IP of your machine in the new data center*. It will work with limited to no downtime at all. Granting that everything is of course set already in the new data center so that diverted traffic will be handled properly.

The important factor now here is your DNS. How good is your DNS in propagating the IP changes. And this works well if we're just talking about one FQDN. If your site is using different domains, they might not all get updated at the same time. Lowering the TTL ahead of your transfer schedule might help.

A good option would be to keep your server in the old data center running while in transition so that if some request will still point there due to domain propagation, the request would still be handled.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your servers send email and you've specified IP addresses in your `SPF records`, you'll need to look into changing.